# My SQL table is missing mysteriously

Tags: mysql-error-1064, mysql

On the live server a table was not found mysteriously. I twas working normally but suddenly i got sql error of missing table. I looked through phpmyadmin i found that a table was really missing mysteriously. It happened first time in my MYSQL life.
Can you please tell me what happened, why the table vanished mysteriously?

Comment: Mysterious things require Scooby Doo.

Comment: Give some more info - where is this server located? MySQL version, table engine, only one table vanished? Possible actions that could have been taken on the DB before existence and mysterious disappearance of the table.

Comment: the same thing just happened to me. really weird. no drop... nothing in logs.. just table gone.

Comment: Have you ever found any clue? Facing same problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a SQL injection attack dropped the table?  Have you checked the database logs?

Comment: No i never dropped it by any means

Comment: SQL injection is not possible because the application is on the server just for testing purposes, nobody knows it. Secondly input validation are implemented and working

Comment: Nothing found in the log about this!\